# Display category name inside image with Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, genesis

I'm using [Magazine Pro Child Theme](http://my.studiopress.com/themes/magazine/#demo-full) for the Genesis Framework. This theme displays the Entry Date inside the featured images at the home page. As far as I know (not a programmer) it uses an apparently simple javascript code to do so:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

// add js body class
$('body').addClass('js');

// find time for each entry and move it inside the image link
$('.home-middle article, .home-top article').each(function(){
    var $time = $(this).find('.entry-time');

    $(this).find('a.alignleft, a.alignnone, a.alignright').append($time);

});
```

I would like to replace the Entry Date for the **Entry Category** of each post. Is it possible just customizing the Javascript file?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean *replace A with B* by saying *replace A for B*? If so, the following should do that.

The only changed part is the code block added to the middle of the `each`'s function.

Note: I guess you want to replace the *red* tooltips in both the top and middle widget area, the following code only does the middle part because I can't find the *category* for the top *featured article* on the page(as you can see, the `if` statement ensures only middle ones are filled with category). Also, new texts filling the red tooltips should be **Leadercaptalized**, change the line between `{}` to `$time.text($widgetArea.find('.widget-title').text().toUpperCase());` if you want wholly captalized ones, or `toLowerCase` for lowercased ones.

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

// add js body class
$('body').addClass('js');

// find time for each entry and move it inside the image link
$('.home-middle article, .home-top article').each(function(){
    var $time = $(this).find('.entry-time');

    var $widgetArea = $time.parents('.home-middle, .home-top');
    if($widgetArea.hasClass('home-middle')) {
        $time.text($widgetArea.find('.widget-title').text());
    }

    $(this).find('a.alignleft, a.alignnone, a.alignright').append($time);

});
```